# Spring Boot: Call your own RestController transactionally

Tags: spring-boot, spring-transactions

I have Spring Boot app which exposes various Rest API endpoints. I would like to call multiple of these endpoints from the application itself using RestTemplate in one **transaction**. Is that possible?

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: No. You cannot do multiple HTTP calls and expect that to be a single transaction. Unless you build your own transactional mechanism over HTTP there is no option to do such a thing.

Comment: Transactions have to be request bounded, just like connections.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to call them from same application, can't you just skip RestTemplate and call your methods directly? Just @Autowired your controllers classes and call their methods sequentially in one transaction.

Comment: I like that approach the most, the only problem is that I am checking permission in the controller via annotations. So I have to get the value from annotation and check the permissions manually.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can do that using [@Transactional](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/Transactional.html) annotation on class header or method header that you need to make an operation of transaction.